# Blank slate invitations - best practices

Tags: guidelines, gui-design

Blank slate invitations (a term taken from the book [Designing Web Interfaces](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/)) are inline invitations/instructions on how to interact with the UI - primarily aimed at novice users. That is, e.g., when no data are yet added, the data-presenting controls of the UI accommodate these instructional overlays. An example could be the text "drag items here" on a blank list of items.

What are your practical experiences with blank slate invitations? Do you have any good examples on how to/not to do it. What are best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a couple of good ones - [Things for Mac](http://culturedcode.com/things/), [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) & Facebook.

There is also one good article written by Jason/DHH from 37signals - [The Blank Slate - Set expectations with a thoughtful first-run experience](http://gettingreal.37signals.com/ch09_The_Blank_Slate.php).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Jason has some good points. I found this post, also by Jason of 37Signals: http://37signals.com/svn/archives/000375.php